# Can Kafka Connect guarantee the write order when RetriableException occurs?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to guarantee the write order when saving data using `SinkTask`.

If I want throw a RetriableException during my `SinkTask.put()`, will `Kafka Connect` write to the datasource ***out of order*** than the order in the partition?

For example, if the messages in a partition is 1-2-3, if an exception occurs during writing Message-2, can Kafka Connect guarantee the messages arrive to the datasource to be 1-2-3?

To my knowledge, Kafka Connect writes to the datasource ***asynchronously***. So it'd seem like the data will arrive to the datasource out of order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, the order of messages will be preserved, but you will have to handle re-delivery of messages.

In your example this means that, if *SinkTask.put* tries to deliver to your sink the following batch of messages: 1,2,3 and fails after writing 1 and before writing 2 by throwing a *RetriableException*, Connect will pause the consumer and will try to re-deliver the batch that failed during the call to *SinkTask.put*. This gives us the aforementioned two effects:

a) Connect will pause the consumer for this task/partition. This means that no other batch of messages will be delivered before the one that failed is retried. Therefore, message order is preserved. E.g. if delivering 1,2,3 fails with *RetriableException*, Connect will not deliver 4,5,6 before it delivers 1,2,3.

b) Connect will retry to deliver the whole message set that failed during *SinkTask.put*. This means that your sink will see again message 1, before it tries to write message 2 for a second time.

Comment: Perfect. Though, I don't quite understand what you mean by *"you will have to handle re-delivery of messages"* since you've mentioned Connect will deliver the messages automatically. Does it mean, the datasource being written to, has to handle duplicate messages being written during a failure? For ex., in your b) example, the datasource needs to handle message 1 being written again properly?

Comment: Right. I based it on your initial example. You mentioned _an exception occurs during writing Message-2_, implying that msg1 was "processed" correctly by the Sink (for instance it was written to a file). When throwing a _RetriableException_ from your Sink, it means that you have a way to re-apply processing of the batch (your sink is idempotent), or you don't care about duplicates. In the example of a file, it means that you have a way to re-append the file that was partially written with just message 1, to contain now message 1,2 and 3 or resolve duplicates. Connect redelivers the whole batch.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful responses and your contribution to Kafka!

Comment: Thanks @KonstantineKarantasis for the response. If we throw `RetriableException` from `put()` for a batch of records, does Kafka-connect send those records to `put()` method again or just retry the batch without sending the records to put()?
e.g. If we count # of records in `put()` and the batch fails with RetriableException, will those records be counted twice or just once?
My understanding is it will count then twice, please let me know if this is correct.